# How to create another contract from another contract using web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

Well I have contract which creates another contract:

```
contractA{    
    function myMethod(address contractbAddress) payable public{
        address contractcAddress = (new contractC).value(msg.value)(msg.sender,address(this),contractbAddress);
        contractB(contractbAddress).setContract(msg.sender,contractcAddress); 
        confirmEvent(msg.sender,contractcAddress);
    }
}
contractB{
    function setContract(address sender,address contractcAddress){
        ....
    }
}
contractC{
    function contractC(address sender,address contractaAddress,address contractbAddress){
        ....
    }
}
```

I have contractB's address and contractA's address when I deployed them using truffle migrate.

Now when I will call function myMethod using web3, how will it get to know what is contractC because they no longer have the source code of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume your function `myMethod` is creating contract C and not B, ie `(new contractC)` instead.

Since you are generating an event with the address you want

```
confirmEvent(msg.sender,contractcAddress);
```

You can listen for that event

```
contractA.events.confirmEvent.watch((err, ev) => {
    console.log(ev); // contract c address is a parameter of the event
});
```

Another option is to request the receipt of the transaction that calls `myMethod` the event should be between the logs of the receipt.

Comment: Yea myMethod is creating creating contract, I will edit that part. But the problem is call to myMethod is always unsuccessful because the deployed contractA doesn't know what contractC is.

Comment: For contractA to be able to create contractC you need to import the file where contractC is defined. If that is a problem you can use the factory pattern.